# How many $4$ digit numbers can be created from $0$, $3$, $4$, $6$, $7$, $9$ under the following conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many $4$ digit numbers can be created from digits: $0$, $3$, $4$, $6$, $7$, $9$? 
I got this as:

$$\dfrac{6!}{2!} = 360$$
To exclude numbers starting with zero: $$\dfrac {5!}{2!} = 60$$
Final result therefore: $$360 - 60 = 300$$
Is this correct?

There are some additional tasks I can't figure out:

a) In how many of them no digit is present more than once?

b) How many of them contain only one digit three times?

c) How many of them are even?

d) How many of them can be divided by $3$ with digit sum of $18$?

Comment: Given task a), I feel like in the original question you are allowed to use digits more than once.

Comment: The way Q a) is given now is what I need. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: What the user above means is that you solved task a), but not the original problem. You are permuting the original digits, not reusing them.

If you are allowed to reuse digits then the answer is $5\cdot 6^3$, as the first digit is non-zero and the other three digits can be any of the six.

Comment: Oh, guess yes, you are allowed to use digits more than once

Comment: If you meant how many $4$-digit numbers can be created from the digits $0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9$ without repetition, then your answer makes sense.  If repetition is permitted, then the answer should be $5 \cdot 6^3$.  In part (b), you have to consider two cases, depending on whether or not $0$ is the repeated digit.  In part (c),  the answer depends on whether repetition is permitted.  The question is poorly worded since it does not specify whether repetition of digits is permitted.

Comment: The repetition is permitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are digits on a four-digit combination lock and $0$ is good in any place, then you have $6^4$ possibilities. If the thousands digit needs to be more than $0$, then there are $5 \cdot 6^3$ possibilities.

But let's continue assuming that a leading zero is all right.

You got (a) already: $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 360$.

For (b), pick the digit that occurs three times ($6$) and where they appear in the number ($_4C_3 = 4$). Then pick the other digit ($5$). So, $6\cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 120$.

For (c), choose which even digit appears in the ones place ($3$) and then pick the other three numbers in order ($5\cdot 4\cdot 3$).

For (d), the divisibility by $3$ is superfluous, since that happens automatically if the digit sum is $18$.
This one just involves some tedious counting. Just start with the big digits and work down.

$(9,9,0,0)$ is one combination. $(9,7,x,x)$ doesn't work, but there is $(9,6,3,0)$ and $(9,3,3,3)$.

For $7$ as the largest digit, we have $(7,7,4,0)$, and that's it.

For $6$ as the largest digit, we have $(6,6,6,0)$, $(6,6,3,3)$, and $(6,4,4,4)$.

There aren't any for $4$ and below, because $4 \cdot 4 = 16 < 18$.

Now, for each of these combinations calculate the number of permutations of the digits, and then add them up. I'll leave that for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Units place= 6 different possibilities 
Tens-place= 6 different possibilities
hundreds place= 6 different possibilities
thousands place =5 different possibilities (can't be zero)

So number of different number is the product 
6x6x6x5= 1080